# Download video from server url faster

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, afnetworking

I'm developing an app in which i'm downloading video from our server and making live photo from it. I've used following code to download it from url. But it's taking so much time to download using `downloadTaskWithRequest` of AFNetworking. Is there any way to do this process faster?

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileVdPath])
        {
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

            NSURL *URL = VideoUrl;
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

            NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

                NSLog(@"vdodownload");
                NSURL *urlFilepath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileVdPath];
                return urlFilepath;

            } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

                if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileImgPath])
                {
                    NSURL *photopathURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fileImgPath];
                    NSURL *videoPathURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fileVdPath];
                    NSLog(@"Video%d",index);
                    [self CreateLivePhoto:photopathURL videoUrl:videoPathURL index:index];
                }

            }];
            [downloadTask resume];

        }
```

Comment: You could try running it on a different thread? Using GCD

Answer (score 0):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` may be faster

Example usage: (Don't forget to add `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` to your info.plist so the saving to camera-roll part works; you can remove that and use it as desired once you verify speed change (if one exists))

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString  *documentsDirectory ;
if ( urlData )
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"videoName.mp4"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, nil, nil, nil);//add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription info.plist

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Grabbed!"
                                                    message:@"We grabbed this video and saved it to your camera roll, feel free to use now!."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```